# how to add a href route with parameter in datatable

Tags: javascript, laravel, datatable

here is i have a datatable based table i have fetched a data from database and displayed using datatable but in this datatable i went to redirect to show for each row of datatable so how to add a route for show with parameter 1d for each row thanks and waiting a positive response!

here is my code

```
<script>
        $(function() {
            $("#start_date").datepicker({
                "dateFormat": "yy-mm-dd"
            });
            $("#end_date").datepicker({
                "dateFormat": "yy-mm-dd"
            });
        });

        // Fetch records
        function fetch(start_date, end_date,zone_id,status_id,sector_id) {
            $.ajax({
                  url: "{{ route('ProjectFilterdate/records') }}",
                type: "GEt",
                data: {
                    start_date: start_date,
                    end_date: end_date,
                    zone_id:zone_id,
                    status_id:status_id,
                    sector_id:sector_id
                },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    // Datatables
                    var i = 1;
                    $('#records').DataTable({
                        "data": data.ptojects,
                        // buttons
                        "dom": "<'row'<'col-sm-12 col-md-4'l><'col-sm-12 col-md-4'B><'col-sm-12 col-md-4'f>>" +
                            "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
                            "<'row'<'col-sm-12 col-md-5'i><'col-sm-12 col-md-7'p>>",
                        "buttons": [
                            'copy','excel', 'pdf', 'print'
                        ],
                        // responsive
                        "responsive": true,
                        "columns": [{
                                "data": "id",
                                "render": function(data, type, row, meta) {
                                    return i++;
                                }
                            },
                             {
                                "data": "code"
                            },
                            {
                                "data": "name"
                            },
                            {
                                "data": "proposal_date"
                            },
                            {
                                "data": "proposal_value"
                            },
                            {
                                "data": "contractor"
                            },
                            {
                                "data": "subcontractor"
                            },
                             
                            {
                            render: function ( data, type, row) {
                              return '<a href="{{route('projects.show','1')}}">test</a>';
                            }
                        },
                    

                        ]
                    });
                }
            });
        }
```

i am trying to make an a href route but i don't know how to add an id parameter
here is the link i am trying

```
{
     render: function ( data, type, row) {
     return '<a href="{{route('projects.show','1')}}">test</a>';
}
```

the place of 1 must be replaced by id for each row

Answer (score -1):

This is how i did t :

```
return DataTables::of($data)->addIndexColumn()
            ->addColumn('project', function ($test) {
            return $test->project->title;
        })
            ->addColumn('action', function ($test) {
            $result = $test->active ? 'btn-success' : 'btn-danger';

            return '<a href="' . route('projectDetail', [
                'id' => $test->id
            ]) . '">detail </a>
                                     ';
        })
            ->rawColumns([
            'action'
        ])
            ->make(true);
    }
```

Comment: hello brother really thanks in advance am trying your answer but still it is an error  like this bro how to solve this one       Undefined variable: id

Comment: I edited my answer, added my complete definition of the datatable. This is a workng example.